# How To Pass My Value In Javascript Arrays Particular Field...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, url, phonegap-build

This Is My JavaScript Array Variable Bubble

```
var bubble = {
        title:"Bubble",
        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble13.mp3",
        oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble12.ogg"
    };
```

in This Line My New Mp3 URL,

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_1 audio').attr("src", data.stanzalist[0].stanzarecordinglist[0].audiopath);
```

I Want To Change My Bubble mp3 Filed URL

I Try Like That Ex,

```
bubble.mp3.attr("src", data.stanzalist[0].stanzarecordinglist[0].audiopath);
```

But This Is Not Working Please Help...?

Comment: `bubble.mp3 = data.stanzalist[0].stanzarecordinglist[0].audiopath`

Comment: Just `bubble.mp3 = newvalue`. Btw bubble is not an array but and object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bubble.mp3 does not have attr method.

```
var bubble = {
    title: "Bubble",
    mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble13.mp3",
    oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble12.ogg"
};

bubble.mp3 = "url you want to change to";
```

... will do this.
You can always log variables to console to inspect what it is:

```
console.log(bubble);
```